# Need to connect shred drive from java which having user name and password but throwing SMBApiException

Tags: java, smb, jcifs, ntlm-authentication

I have tried Ntlm but it dint work so I tried smb

```
       SMBClient client1 = new SMBClient(SmbConfig.createDefaultConfig());
        Connection c = client1.connect("myhost");
        Session s = c.authenticate(new AuthenticationContext("myuser", 
        "test".toCharArray(), ""));
        DiskShare share = (DiskShare) s.connectShare("smb");
```

but this is throwing error that

```
     com.hierynomus.mssmb2.SMBApiException: STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE (0xc000006d): Authentication 
     failed for  'myuser' using com.hierynomus.smbj.auth.NtlmAuthenticator@5d9be807
      com.hierynomus.protocol.transport.TransportException: java.net.SocketException: 
     Connection reset
```

Comment: You have a password of 'test' on the share?

Comment: no I just edited that I have right username and password. I am able connect frm windows machine but not able to connect from my code

Comment: If you can provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I'll try it on my Samba server

Comment: Should you be using `""` as the domain?  Try your real domain instead.